# How would I query data from a field in table B with a foreign key in table A that belongs to table B?

Tags: python, html, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I want to use organiser_id from Edetails to query forename in User and display it on an html page

What would I have to write in HERE to do so?
ignore unclosed loops/selection, code is too long

```
     {% for event in edetails %}
        {% if event.weekday == "Monday" %}
        {% if event.clubOrEvent == "club" or event.weeknum == thisweek %}
                <div class="modal-body">
                  Date/Starting Date: {{ event.date }}
                  <br>
                  Open to year: {{ event.yearGroup }}
                  <br>
                  Organiser: {{ **HERE** }}
                </div>
```

views.py defining view for home.html

```
from flask import Blueprint, render_template
from flask_login import current_user
from .models import Edetails,User
from datetime import date

views = Blueprint('views', __name__)

#defining homepage to be home.html

@views.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def home():
    return render_template(
        "home.html",
        user=current_user,
        edetails=Edetails.query.all(),
        thisweek = (date.today()).isocalendar()[1],
        users = User.query.all()
    )
```

models.py where tables defined

```
from . import db
from flask_login import UserMixin


#defining tables in the database

class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(15))
    forename = db.Column(db.String(50))
    surname = db.Column(db.String(50))
    email = db.Column(db.String, unique=True)
    password= db.Column(db.String(50))
    events = db.relationship('Edetails')

class Edetails(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(30))
    maxSpaces = db.Column(db.Integer)
    date = db.Column(db.Date)
    time = db.Column(db.Time)
    location = db.Column(db.String(50))
    yearGroup = db.Column(db.String(50))
    weekday = db.Column(db.Integer)
    clubOrEvent = db.Column(db.String(5))
    description = db.Column(db.String(300))
    organiser_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
    weeknum = db.Column(db.Integer)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example below shows you how to make the organizer of type `User` accessible in `Edetails` using [`relationship`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/relationship_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.relationship).

```py
class Edetails(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

    # ...

    organiser_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
    organiser = db.relationship('User')
```

The organizer of the event can be queried with the attribute `organiser`. The first name can therefore also be reached.

```
Organiser: {{ event.organiser.forename }}
```